# Insert other shape with shapepar and cutout

Tags: graphics, wrap, shapepar

How to fix this code so that the text clipping the picture? I'm not able to edit the initial commands.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\cutout{r}(-20mm,155mm)
\shapepar{{180.449753}%
{0.0}b{239.0}%
\\{0.0}t{239.0}{24.0}%
\\{0.0}b{239.0}%
\\{0.0}t{239.0}{24.0}%
\\{5.920649}t{211.0}{81.0}%
\\{12.0}t{196.0}{111.0}%
\\{24.0}t{178.0}{148.0}%
\\{36.0}t{165.0}{173.0}%
\\{48.0}t{156.0}{189.0}%
\\{60.0}t{149.0}{202.0}%
\\{72.0}t{145.0}{210.0}%
\\{84.0}t{141.0}{216.0}%
\\{96.0}t{139.0}{220.0}%
\\{108.0}t{138.0}{222.0}%
\\{120.0}t{137.0}{224.0}%
\\{132.0}t{138.0}{223.0}%
\\{144.0}t{138.0}{223.0}%
\\{154.757495}t{139.0}{222.0}%
\\{156.0}t{139.0}{222.0}%
\\{168.0}t{140.0}{221.0}%
\\{180.0}t{142.0}{218.0}%
\\{192.0}t{144.0}{216.0}%
\\{204.0}t{147.0}{212.0}%
\\{216.0}t{151.0}{208.0}%
\\{219.515642}t{152.0}{207.0}%
\\{228.0}t{156.0}{202.0}%
\\{240.0}t{166.0}{192.0}%
\\{242.135455}t{168.0}{190.0}%
\\{244.643273}t{174.0}{8.0}t{183.0}{175.0}%
\\{252.0}t{174.0}{183.0}%
\\{252.224841}t{174.0}{183.0}%
\\{264.0}t{158.0}{199.0}%
\\{276.0}t{145.0}{212.0}%
\\{288.0}t{138.0}{219.0}%
\\{300.0}t{130.0}{226.0}%
\\{312.0}t{116.0}{240.0}%
\\{324.0}t{105.0}{251.0}%
\\{330.465228}t{100.0}{256.0}%
\\{336.0}t{96.0}{260.0}%
\\{348.0}t{89.0}{266.0}%
\\{360.0}t{83.0}{272.0}%
\\{372.0}t{78.0}{276.0}%
\\{384.0}t{73.0}{281.0}%
\\{396.0}t{68.0}{285.0}%
\\{408.0}t{62.0}{290.0}%
\\{420.0}t{54.0}{296.0}%
\\{432.0}t{44.0}{305.0}%
\\{444.0}t{34.0}{312.0}%
\\{450.776477}t{28.0}{317.0}%
\\{456.0}t{24.0}{320.0}%
\\{468.0}t{14.0}{327.0}%
\\{480.0}t{6.0}{331.0}%
\\{492.0}t{0.0}{333.0}%
\\{504.0}t{1.0}{328.0}%
\\{516.0}t{24.0}{301.0}%
\\{528.0}t{77.0}{244.0}%
\\{529.778338}t{85.0}{235.0}%
\\{540.0}t{124.0}{191.0}%
\\{552.0}t{172.0}{135.0}%
\\{556.773109}t{192.0}{111.0}%
\\{564.0}t{227.0}{64.0}%
\\{567.717726}t{254.0}{22.0}%
\\{567.717726}e{254.0}%
}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
  \vspace{10mm}
  \centerline{\tikz[overlay]%
    \node{
      \includegraphics[width=35mm]{business-women}
    };
  }
\end{minipage} \par
\lipsum*[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you better off with `wrapfig` for this.

Comment: But wrapfig accepts clippings?

Comment: My understanding from your figure you want the lady to move up to the top opening at the right?

Comment: I just want to break the lines, keeping the figure exactly where you are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want it as a shape or as a right window?
Here is an example for a window:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cutwin,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\opencutright
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\leavevmode\put(0,-50){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{/tmp/Business-Women.eps}}}
\begin{cutout}{3}{0.75\textwidth}{0pt}{11}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]
\end{cutout}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking you an unrelated question, sometimes I see in code `\par\leavevmode` rather than `leavevmode` would this normally make any difference?

Comment: no, in the second case the `leavmode` maybe superflous if you are already in the hoirizontal mode

Comment: Are there any other packages (beside cutwin and shapepar) able to cutout or reflow text around shapes/images?